# how to run MASM32 in notepad++

Tags: masm32

Can someone help me how to run a masm file?
I tried to link this file, but CMD says the file is invalid or corrupted.

Error code `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "Hello.asm"`

Here is my Hello.asm code file:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.stack 4096 
.data
hello db "Hello Word " , 0
.code 
_start:
    push offset hello
    call StdOut 
    invoke ExitProcess , 0  
end  _start
```

my syntax when the above file is `C:\Users\Vinh\RunCodeASM>link Hello.asm`

My Hello.asm file and my masm32 folder are both in the RunCodeASM folder.

Thanks you !!

Comment: What is the command you ran, does Notepad++ have to do with it?

Comment: Sorry and Thank you @IMSoP . Next time I will consider how to write and ask questions

Comment: I have edited the question again. The command I ran in the question, but it can't open this file
With Notepad++ , I just write the code and save it as a .asm . file
Where I save this Hello.asm file is the RunCodeASM folder (this folder only contains the masm32 assembler and the Hello.asm file)

Comment: You need to assemble your `.asm` file into a `.obj` file, which you then can pass to the linker.